# How to update livedata through a method with multiple parameters

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I have this livedata "events" that should be updated if the method loadEvents() gets fired. The thing is, I need to pass many different parameters to that method. If I call this method and then observe the data, the data is null. How can I do this？

Viewmodel:

```
private val _events = MutableLiveData<List<BookEvent>>()
   val events: LiveData<List<BookEvent>> get() = _events

   fun loadEvents( dateTo: String,
                           dateFrom: String?,
                           dateTime: String?,
                           pageIndex: Int,
                           types: String){
       viewModelScope.launch {
           val response = eventsBooksRepository.getEvents(
               pageSize = 100,
               pageIndex = pageIndex + 1,
               types = types,
               dateTime= dateTime,
               dateFrom = dateFrom)

           if(response.value?.isSuccessful() == true){
               _events.value = response.value?.data
           } else {
               _events.value = null
           }
       }
   }
```

In my fragment, getEvents() works if I don't call retrieveEvents() first but I need to call retrieveEvents() with different parameters, depending on the different outcomes. If I call retrieveEvents() then I get "java.lang.NullPointerException: it must not be null" when observing the events.

Fragment:

```
private fun retrieveEvents(){
       lifecycleScope.launch {
           myViewModel.loadEvents(
               dateTime= if (eventsByDate) dateTime else "",
               dateFrom = if (previousEvents) dayDateFrom else "",
               pageIndex = 1,
               types = myViewModel.filtersApplied
           )
       }
   }

   private fun getEvents(){
       myViewModel.events.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
           val events = it.map { event ->
               val descriptionPair = getEventIcon(event)
               bookEventModel.bookEventItem(
                   bookEventModel(
                       event.eventId,
                       event.eventType,
                       event.eventDate,
                       event.bookState
                   )
               )

           }
           
           binding.eventsRecycler.adapter = eventsAdapter
           eventsAdapter.addAll(events)
       }
   }
```

How can I call retrieveEvents() whenever I want to update the livedata without getting a null object?

Answer (score 1):

This is the `LiveData` you're observing:

```
val events: LiveData<List<BookEvent>>
```

The data is holds is a *non-null type*, `List<BookEvent>`. So when you call `observe` on it and pass your lambda function, that function's inferred type is `(List<BookEvent>) -> Unit` - i.e. it takes a **non-null** `List<BookEvent>` parameter, because that's the type that `events` emits.

So you're calling `it.map` and you're not getting warned to null-check `it`, because that parameter is (implicitly) declared as non-null. But `it` **is** getting passed a null somehow, and that's why you're getting the crash.

Probably because of this:

```
if(response.value?.isSuccessful() == true){
    _events.value = response.value?.data
} else {
    _events.value = null
}
```

You're explicitly setting `events`'s value to *null* even though it's meant to *only* hold `List<BookEvent>`s. You're able to do this (even though you shouldn't) because `LiveData` uses *null* as a "no data" value when it's first created, if you don't provide an initial value. That initial placeholder null won't be emitted and observed - like you said, calling `getEvents()` works fine, observing the `LiveData` with no value doesn't trigger the observer and crash it with a null value.

It's only when you call `retrieveEvents` and explicitly set a null value on `events` that it emits that as a value, and that hits your observer function and causes all kinds of trouble. You're doing that intentionally as a fallback for when your fetch fails, which is a problem in itself - none of your observers are expecting a *null* value, they can't handle it. So either don't make that your fallback value (use `emptyList()`, or maybe you don't want to push an update at all if it fails?) or make your `LiveData` nullable, i.e. `LiveData<List<BookEvent>?>`

---

By the way, here's what happens for me if I try and set a non-nullable `LiveData` to null:

[image: Android Studio showing an error when setting a non-nullable LiveData to null]

Aren't you getting that warning? It won't stop you from building the app and running it, until you hit that null and it crashes, but it should at least be pointing out the problem to you. Make sure you're using [an up-to-date version of the `LiveData` lifecycle library](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle) in your gradle dependencies

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I am not getting that warning in the first place but I'm going to look into this. Thanks!

Comment: @dazai that's why I suggested checking what version of the livedata library you're using - you might not even have it as an explicit dependency, meaning you're getting whatever older version another dependency is pulling in, and that warning might have been added in a later version. I've definitely had behaviour issues before that were solved that way, so definitely worth trying!

Answer (score 0):

** In your fragment check null for the events observer**

You call view model methods directly until it's suspend function
Like this

```
myViewModel.loadEvents()
```

Another suggestion use dispatchers to the scope and add errorHandler else try catch block.

Follow like this

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO + CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
    //Handle exceptions here
       Log.e(TAG,exception.message)
    }){
      //Set method for the main thread. Use Post Value.
        _events.postValue(response.value?.data)
     //OR
       viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main){
         _events.value(response.value?.data)
       }
    }
```

Comment: But I'm calling loadEvents to get the _events to fill so why is it null?

Comment: `events`'s data is only *null* internally, because it doesn't have an initial value. It won't emit anything until a value is set, which is why it's safe to `observe` `LiveData` objects with no initial value - it would be chaos otherwise! Like the OP says, they can observe it fine, it's only when they call the function that sets a value (including a possible *null*) that it breaks